# Fast Way to Replace Names with Ids in Datatable?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy, import-csv

I have a very large CSV file I have to load on a regular basis that contains time series data. Examples of the headers are below:

```
| SiteName | Company | Date | ResponseTime | Clicks |
```

This data comes from a service external to the uploader. `SiteName` and `Company` are both string fields. In the database these are normalized. There is a `Site` table and a `Company` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Site] (
    [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Company] (
    [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
)
```

As well as the data table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SiteStatistics] (
    [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [CompanyId] INT NOT NULL,
    [SiteId] INT NOT NULL,
    [DataTime] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [SiteStatisticsToSite_FK] FOREIGN KEY ([SiteId]) REFERENCES [Site]([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [SiteStatisticsToCompany_FK] FOREIGN KEY ([CompanyId]) REFERENCES [Company]([Id])
)
```

At around 2 million rows in the CSV file any sort of IO-bound iteration isn't going to work. I need this done in minutes, not days.

My initial thought is that I could pre-load `Site` and `Company` into DataTables. I already have the CSV loaded into a datatable in the format that matches the CSV columns. I need to now replace every `SiteName` with the Id field of `Site` and every `Company` with the Id field of `Company`. What is the quickest, most efficient way to handle this?

Comment: my first step for jobs like this is to get the csv into a db table as is so i do not have the IO overhead as you have mentioned.  from there it's just the normal sql operations to get what you want.  from ssms (for example) you can import from a file as the first step but we can't tell what you're using

Comment: The end goal is to send it off to SMSS using bulk copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go with Pre-Loading the Sites and Company's you can get the distinct values using code:

```
DataView view = new DataView(table);
DataTable distinctCompanyValues = view.ToTable(true, "Company")

DataView view = new DataView(table);
DataTable distinctSiteValues = view.ToTable(true, "Site")
```

Then load those two DataTables into their SQL Tables using Sql-Bulk-Copy.

---

Next dump all the data in:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SiteStatistics] (
    [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [CompanyId] INT DEFAULT  0,
    [SiteId] INT DEFAULT 0,
    [Company] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Site] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    [DataTime] DATETIME NOT NULL
)
```

---

Then do an UPDATE to set the Referential Integrity fields:

```
UPDATE [SiteStatistics] ss SET
[CompanyId] = (SELECT Id FROM [Company] c Where ss.[Company] = c.Name),
[SiteId] = (SELECT Id FROM [Site] s Where ss.[Site] = s.Name)
```

Add the Foreign Key constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE [SiteStatistics] ADD CONSTRAINT [SiteStatisticsToSite_FK] FOREIGN KEY ([SiteId]) REFERENCES [Site]([Id])
ALTER TABLE [SiteStatistics] ADD CONSTRAINT [SiteStatisticsToCompany_FK] FOREIGN KEY ([CompanyId]) REFERENCES [Company]([Id])
```

---

Finally delete the Site & Company name fields from SiteStatistics:

```
ALTER TABLE [SiteStatistics] DROP COLUMN [Company];
ALTER TABLE [SiteStatistics] DROP COLUMN [Site];
```